# Is it OK to post restricted challenges where only some people may participate?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, challenges

Recently a [Friendly Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8378/31562) was posted on Code Review Meta where PPCG challenged Code Review.

The post on Code Review Meta says:

> I am planning on hosting a King of the Hill challenge Programming Puzzles and Code Golf VS. Code Review.

This challenge got me thinking: Is it okay to post a challenge on PPCG where only some people are "allowed" to participate?

Answer (score 24):

## No

There is absolutely no benefit to restricting a question to users of a certain type.  This is would only serve to make users who are not allowed to participate unhappy.

However,  I do think it is perfectly fine to separate users into separate categories, as was done in [Red vs. Blue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots).  As long as the categories are properly symmetric, such that users on both sides are treated with the same challenge.

Comment: *`perfectly fine to separate users into separate categories`* Which I *think* this is. It uses an odd delineation (users of PPCG vs. CR; presumably users on both sites would have to either pick a side or use the one with the highest rep) but *any given user* can participate and participate in the *same* challenge on teams (like Red vs. Blue).

Comment: @Draco18s But this doesn't really make sense, because challenge on this site are for the users of this site, not for users of Code Review.

Answer (score 9):

If you are talking about specific **users** then:

## No

---

If you are talking about users with a **[particular set of skills](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/29/2929bc25a08c05be8582a16599ca2e57fe9b960da86de991d84c50b4c7540228.jpg)**, then it's a bit more nuanced. It's frowned upon (for good reasons) to only allow certain languages in "normal challenges", such as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

However, if the challenge is a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)-challenge then it makes sense to only allow submissions in for instance Java or JavaScript. Such a restriction will leave many of us out of the competition, unless we're willing to put in the effort to learn a new language.